# Why duplicate column in flutter sqflite, when array variable is used

Tags: flutter, dart, sqflite

I followed simple [sqflite](https://suragch.medium.com/simple-sqflite-database-example-in-flutter-e56a5aaa3f91) example, It works and I uninstall and install and then run again and it works.

I changed code

```
static final columnId = '_id';
static final columnName = 'name';
static final columnAge = 'age';
...
CREATE TABLE $table (
  $columnId INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
  $columnName TEXT NOT NULL,
  $columnAge INTEGER NOT NULL
)
```

to following

```
static final List<String> columns4Table = ['_id', 'name', 'age'];
...
CREATE TABLE $table (
 $columns4Table[0] INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
 $columns4Table[1] TEXT NOT NULL,
 $columns4Table[2] INTEGER NOT NULL
)
```

..

After this changes, when the application is run, I get following error even though application was uninstalled as if duplicate table.

> duplicate column name: _id, name, age  error
> DatabaseException(duplicate column name: _id, name, age (code 1): ,
> while compiling: CREATE TABLE my_table (
> [_id, name, age][0] INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
> [_id, name, age](https://suragch.medium.com/simple-sqflite-database-example-in-flutter-e56a5aaa3f91) TEXT NOT NULL,
> [_id, name, age][2] INTEGER NOT NULL
> )) sql '          CREATE TABLE my_table (
> [_id, name, age][0] INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
> [_id, name, age](https://suragch.medium.com/simple-sqflite-database-example-in-flutter-e56a5aaa3f91) TEXT NOT NULL,
> [_id, name, age][2] INTEGER NOT NULL
> )
> ' args [] during open, closing...

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
CREATE TABLE $table (
 $columns4Table[0] INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
 $columns4Table[1] TEXT NOT NULL,
 $columns4Table[2] INTEGER NOT NULL
)
```

To

```
CREATE TABLE $table (
 "${columns4Table[0]}" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
 "${columns4Table[1]}" TEXT NOT NULL,
 "${columns4Table[2]}" INTEGER NOT NULL
 )
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63260535/flutter-sqflite-sql-begin-exclusive-args-during-open-closing